# Using Java Mail to verify an email with signature from Outlook 2013

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail, digital-signature, x509certificate

I send an email with signature to my inbox. Then I use Java Mail to receive the mail and verify the signature. But there always a error message '**message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value**'.

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value
at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(SignerInformation.java:517)
at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(SignerInformation.java:601)
```

I use maven

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
>         <version>1.4.5</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- Bouncy Castle Provider -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
>         <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
>         <version>1.54</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- BC Mail -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
>         <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
>         <version>1.54</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

This line I got an exception:

```
 verify = signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(certificate));
```

Here are my codes:

```
    public static void receiveSignedMail(Message msg) throws MessagingException {
    try {
        SMIMESigned signed = new SMIMESigned((MimeMultipart) msg.getContent());
        if (isValid(signed)) {
            System.out.println("verification succeeded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("verification failed");
        }
        signed = new SMIMESigned((MimeMultipart) msg.getContent());
         MimeBodyPart content = signed.getContent();
         System.out.println("Content: " + content.getContent());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}

public static boolean isValid(CMSSignedData signedData) {
    try {
        SignerInformationStore signers = signedData.getSignerInfos();
        Iterator<SignerInformation> it = signers.getSigners().iterator();
        boolean verify = false;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            SignerInformation signer = it.next();
            org.bouncycastle.util.Store store = (org.bouncycastle.util.Store) signedData.getCertificates();
            Collection certCollection = ((org.bouncycastle.util.Store) store).getMatches(signer.getSID());
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
            X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next();
            X509Certificate certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(certHolder);
            verify = signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(certificate));
        }
        return verify;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return false;
    }
}

public static Folder getFolder(String folderName) {
    try {
        String host = "your mail server";
        boolean auth = true;
        /* You must use SSL for incoming mail, SSL ports are 993 for IMAP and 995 for POP3 */
        /* To support SSL, using protocl 'pop3s' or 'imaps' */
        String port = "993";
        String receivingProtocol = "imaps";
        String username = "your email address";
        String password = "your email password";

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", auth);
        props.put("mail.store.protocol", receivingProtocol);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore(receivingProtocol);
        store.connect(host, username, password);
        Folder folder = store.getFolder(folderName);
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        return folder;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And a main method to run it

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    try {
        String inbox = "Your Inbox";
        Folder folder = getFolder(inbox);
        SearchTerm st = new OrTerm(new FromStringTerm("search condition"), new SubjectTerm("search condition"));
        Message[] messages = folder.search(st);
        int mailCounts = messages.length;
        System.out.println("Found: " + mailCounts + " mails matched with the condition.");

        if (messages.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No Message!");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("the " + (i + 1) + " mail" + "------------------------------------------------");
            MimeMessage mail = (MimeMessage) messages[i];
            String out_from = ((InternetAddress) messages[i].getFrom()[0]).getAddress();
            System.out.println("From:" + out_from);
            System.out.println("Subject:" + messages[i].getSubject());
            System.out.println("Type: " + mail.getContentType());
            if (mail.isMimeType("multipart/signed")) {
                System.out.println("a signed mail");
                receiveSignedMail(mail);
            }
        }
        folder.close(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show to which line in your code that exception points? And maybe give some additional info on the headers you receive. Yo you have unlimited strength JCE extensions in place?

Comment: You might be interested in this BC article: [CMS and SMIME APIs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/CMS+and+SMIME+APIs), in particular its sections **Outlook and Outlook Express Issues with Signed Email and Nested Multiparts** and **Outlook Express Issues with Signed Email**.

Comment: Any solutions yet? The article doesn't helpped me. (BCMail 1.56)

Comment: Here you can find a "simple" example to perform S/MIME signature validation with Bouncy Castle, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023657/320594

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with all other email clients (Thunderbird, Outlook, etc...), but i was able to solve it. I think this problem is caused by a bug in the *javax.mail* library.

I am using the following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
     <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
     <version>1.62</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.62</version>
</dependency>
```

**Solution:**

When polling the emails from your email server via IMAP, you receive them as an **Message** object array:

```
Message[] messages = pollFolder.getMessages();
```

Now you are going to iterate over this array and process each message separately. This means, you are working directly with the **Message** object.

But if you want to verify the mail's signature with Bouncy Castle, you need to use a **MimeMessage** object instead (see the [official example](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/ReadSignedMail.java) code from Bouncy Castle; code line 93)

To transform a **Message** into the **MimeMessage**, you normally need to cast the object in this way:

```
MimeMessage mimeMsg = (MimeMessage) message;
```

But this didn't work correctly for some reason, so I've got  the following exception later, when verifying the email signature with Bouncy Castle: `org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value`

What I've done as a workaround was, *to copy* the already casted **MimeMessage** object, under use of the **MimeMessage** constructor!!!

So **THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM** for me:

```
MimeMessage mimeMsg = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage) message);
```

**Here is the full working code**:

```
Message message = // get Message from folder...
MimeMessage mimeMsg = new MimeMessage((MimeMessage) message);
boolean emailSignatureValid = verifySignature(mimeMsg);

 // code from Bouncy Castle
 public boolean verifySignature(MimeMessage signedMimeMessage) {
    try {
        if (signedMimeMessage.isMimeType("multipart/signed")) {
            SMIMESignedParser s = new SMIMESignedParser(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build(), (MimeMultipart) signedMimeMessage.getContent());
            return verify(s);
        } else if (signedMimeMessage.isMimeType("application/pkcs7-mime")) {
            SMIMESignedParser s = new SMIMESignedParser(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build(), signedMimeMessage);
            return verify(s);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This mimeMessage is not signed: " + EmailPrinter.printMessage(signedMimeMessage));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not verify signature of mimeMessage", e);
        return false;
    }
}

 // code from Bouncy Castle
 private static boolean verify(SMIMESignedParser s) throws Exception {

    Store certs = s.getCertificates();
    SignerInformationStore signers = s.getSignerInfos();
    Collection c = signers.getSigners();
    Iterator it = c.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) it.next();
        Collection certCollection = certs.getMatches(signer.getSID());
        Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
        X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider(BC).getCertificate((X509CertificateHolder) certIt.next());
        try {
            return signer.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider(BC).build(cert));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occured during verification",e);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I know this is an weird workaround, but it was the only way, I could solve the problem. I hope you find it useful too.

cheers!

BEEveloper

Comment: HI. I am trying to validate if user is able to recieve an outlook email in his inbox, with a particular subject name. The code should work if user is logged in to oulook or he may not be. COuld you please guide me in this case please.. any references..

Comment: I dont't exactly understand, why you need outlook?

Normally all emails are stored (as you already said) in the users inbox. This is a special "part" of an Email-Server system. You can access these E-Mails in the inbox via the IMAP or POP3 protocol. Outlook is NOT the email server where the emails are stored in the inbox. It is just the client to download and display those emails (via IMAP or POP3).

So, what you need to do is, to establish a connection to the IMAP / POP3 server of your email provider (e.g. Gmail).
After this you can get all emails and check the subject field in java.